# Как проверить авторизацию?

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте!

Изучаю C# и возникла идея программно авторизоваться на сайте. Как проверить, авторизовался ли я или нет ?

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.site.ru/");

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "user");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "password");

foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
{
    if (he.GetAttribute("value").Equals("login"))
    {
        he.InvokeMember("click");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: после клика браузер открывает новую страницу, или загружает новые данные...
Достаточно определить, чем отличается страница логина от страницы поле логина, найти какой-либо универсальный тег, который отсутствует на странице логина, но присутствует на странице после логина, или наоборот, и  искать его. если он есть, значит логин произошел успешно...

ну, как-то так..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, что в `webBrowser1` была установлена кука, соответствующая ситуации, когда вы залогинены на данный сайт - думаю, что понять, так это или нет по cookie можно однозначно в 95% случаев.

Comment: @Asen2 с возвращением :D

Comment: спасибо, так я наверное и попробую сделать )

Comment: @AlexWindHope Я еще даже комментировать вопросы не могу, так что пока не интересно =)